# Adding a link from javascript to php script

Tags: php, javascript

I have following script, which is not working. What to I do to add the link?
    jno = "97856483";
    dispTitle = "new book";
    dispAuthor = "authorname";

```
document.getElementById('popups').innerHTML = '';
//Add link to add this book:
 var url = encodeURIComponent(jno) + "&tt=" + encodeURIComponent(dispTitle) + "&at=" + encodeURIComponent(dispAuthor);
 //document.writeln(url);
 document.getElementById("addLink").innerHTML = "<a href='memaccountentry.php?isbn='+ url>Add book</a>" ;   //This one just appends the word url.
//window.location.href =  'memaccountentry.php?isbn=' +jno +'&tt=' +dispTitle+'&at=' +dispAuthor;          //I know this is working, but not a right way to do. 
//I need to put a href link to go to the next page. 
//ajax.open('GET', 'memaccountentry.php?isbn=' +jno +'&tt=' +dispTitle+'&at=' +dispAuthor', true);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to properly open and close your quotes.
Try that:

```
document.getElementById("addLink").innerHTML = "<a href='memaccountentry.php?isbn="+ url +"'>Add book</a>" ;   //This one just appends the word url.
```

Comment: There is one single quote before memaccountentry, which is never closed.

Comment: Thanks.. now I got it. I was searching for this simple thing for hours.. A vote up!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, dont forget to flag it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't format your string correctly.

If this is not what you wanted, then you have me completely confused.

```
document.getElementById("addLink").innerHTML = "<a href='memaccountentry.php?isbn='" + url + ">Add book</a>";
```

Comment: It just shows memaccountentry.php?isbn=  and nothing else. The url is not appended to the link.